# iterm2 first tab transparency differs from default

Tags: iterm

I set up iTerm2 colours/backgrounds, however the first tab is always "lighter" (i.e. more transparent) than all the other tabs. When I set transparency in the profiles, I can see every tab except the first one adjusting. Is it some bug or some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean the tab itself or the whole window associated to that tab?  When I adjust the transparency with the slider in Preferences/Profiles/Window all my tab screens change with the slider. Including the 1st.

Comment: Do you have a background image?

Comment: no background image. i'm using it as visor, so there is only one window, and it's only the first tab, if i open a new tab, it has proper opacity. if i close that first tab, everything is fine, all new tabs are ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case this was due to HotKey windows was created after pressing hotkey, but after CMD+T new tab was created with Default profile. So you can either set HotKey as default or rework your shortcuts. You can experience with this by clicking right mouse button -> New Window/New Tab and then Default /HotKey Window profile. After you will define what you would expect here it should be easier to configure

Answer (score 1):

Just sorted this myself. The trick is in "Preferences > Profiles > Hotkey Window * > Window", uncheck the box for "Open in a new window, never in a tab"

* <sup>Note that "Hotkey Window" is just how profile is called for me (using a dropdown terminal), if might be "default" or something else. Try each profile until the one you want is affected.</sup>